# Files and generating numbers ,c programming

Tags: c

Task is next:
After you generate 20 random numbers and read informations from file tombula.txt which contains names of users and their 9 numbers,print the first user (his/her name) who has 3  numbers from own array equal to generated numbers.

This is my part of code where i generate numbers and read from file but I don't know how to find that first person who has 3 numbers from array equal to generated numbers,if you know how to write that please help:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

    typedef struct
    {   char name[50];
        int num[8];
    }someone;

void generating(int[]);
int check(int[], int);


int main(void)
{
    someone *pK = NULL;
    int i, j, count = 0, tip;
    FILE *F;
    int generated[30];
    int brojac[5];

    srand(time(NULL));
    generating(generated);

    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        printf("%d ", generated[j]);
    printf("\n\n\n");
    F = fopen("tombula.txt", "r");
    if (F == NULL)
    {
        printf("error!");
        exit(1);
    }

    i = 0;
    while (feof(F) == 0)
    {
        pK = ((someone *)realloc(pK, (i + 1)*sizeof(someone)));

        fscanf(F, "%s", pK[i].name);
        for (j = 0; j < 8; j++)
            fscanf(F, "%d", &pK[i].num[j]);

        i++;
        count++;
    }
    i--;
    count--;

    for (int z = 0; z < count; z++){
        printf("%s ", pK[z].name);
        for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++){
            printf("%d ", pK[z].num[k]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }







    return 0;
}


void generating(int numbers[])
{
    int i, tmp;

    for (i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        tmp = rand() % 50 + 1;
        if (check(numbers, tmp))
        {
            --i;
            continue;
        }
        numbers[i] = tmp;
    }
}

int check(int b[], int a){
    int i;
    int n = 8;

    for (i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        if (b[i] == a)
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: First think about how you would tackle the problem by hand.  Once you have that, translate it into code.

Comment: An example for your problem might help. Be clear what are you asking for.

Answer (score 0):

1.You opened file in `r` mode.

2.In a loop (loop must work until EOF) read data stored in file using `fscanf()` .Store `name` into `char array` and `number` into `integer array` (As you defined in struct).

3.Inside loop check if the `3 numbers` matches with the numbers `generated` and if they do `print` the persons `name` and use `break` to come out of loop.

4.After this `close` the file.

Comment: how to check  if the 3 numbers matches with the numbers generated?

Comment: @TomislavBaričević   Numbers generated are stored in what ? If in array then by first `3` index of generated number array and that you read from file can be compared .